# How to detect content-type automatically in Angular

Tags: angular

In my Angular 9 application I am trying to automatically set the content-type for every different HTTP request I do.

In [Angular doc](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#detectContentTypeHeader) I found this `detectContentTypeHeader` method but it seems not working good.
In my case for example for this type of body:

`{"username":"admin","password":"pwd","tenant":"12345"}`

it detects `text/plain` instead of `application/json` but the body is a correct JSON, so am I wrong something?
Is there a way to do it automatically or I need to set it for every request?
(I am already using an interceptor)

multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in an `object` instead of a `string` as the request body it will detect it as `application/json`.

The reason it's detecting a string as `text/plain` is written in the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.2/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L287)

> Technically, strings could be a form of JSON data, but it's safe enough to assume they're plain strings

If for some reason you still want to detect a string as a valid JSON you can do the following:

```
let contentType = req.detectContentTypeHeader();

if (typeof req.body === 'string') {
  try {
    JSON.parse(req.body);
    contentType = 'application/json';
  } catch {}
}

req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('content-type', contentType) });
```

Comment: Sorry but isn't this body an object? `{"username":"admin","password":"pwd"}`

Comment: @AlessandroCeleghin that's hard to tell, you should do a `typeof` the value and log this in the console, it most likely is a stringified version of the object, otherwise Angular wouldn't detect it as `text/plain`.

Comment: You really shouldn’t have to set the content type at all. Angular is pretty good in determining the correct one for you. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, probably it's better to don't set contentType manually. So I need to update some of my body to make it works automatically.